# In what direction is the photodiode placed in a CMOS image sensor?

Tags: cmos, photodiode, image-sensor

I am currently trying to understand how a CMOS Active Pixel Sensor (APS) works. I came across two different diagrams (one in a presentation, the other one from wikipedia). Which is the correct way to put the diode?
I would imagine the holes produced in the second circuit to immediately flow off to GND.

Also wouldn't the RST need to be kept always on to reverse bias the diode? But then you cannot build up a voltage from incident light, can you? Or does it also work without bias?

[image: first way to put diode]

[image]

Comment: The detector region of that pixel, the photodiode, needs to be reverse-biased. The 2nd circuit seems correct. But the 1rst circuit will work, if the substrate is tied to +V; in that case, the Nchannels will be in wells.

Answer (score 2):

Photodiodes can work either way. In the photovoltaic case they provide a forward bias voltage when illuminated. The other approach is to apply a reverse bias voltage and a current flows when illuminated.

Looks like the 2nd circuit charges the gate capacitance and uses the PD to discharge it, and the 1st circuit discharges the gate capacitance and the PD charges it.